# How to apply ndimage.generic_filter()

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to learn ndimage and I can't figure how [generic_filter()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.generic_filter.html) function works. Documentation mentions that user function is to be applied to user defined footprint, but somehow I can't make it. Here is example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy import ndimage
>>> im = np.ones((20, 20)) * np.arange(20)
>>> footprint = np.array([[0,0,1],
...                       [0,0,0],
...                       [1,0,0]])
... 
>>> def test(x):
...     return x * 0.5
... 
>>> res = ndimage.generic_filter(im, test, footprint=footprint)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<Engine input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\ndimage\filters.py", line 1142, in generic_filter
    cval, origins, extra_arguments, extra_keywords)
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

I expected that `x` value passed to `test()` function, are those True footprint neighboring elements for each array sample, so in this example arrays with shape (2,), but I get above error.

What am I doing wrong?
How can I tell generic filter to apply simple value calculation on specified neighboring points?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The function passed to `ndimage.generic_filter` must map an array to a scalar. The array will be 1-dimensional, and contain the values from `im` which have been "selected" by the `footprint`.

For each location in `res`, the value returned by the function is the value assigned to that location. That's why, naturally, the function needs to return a scalar.

So, for example,

```
def test(x):
    return (x*0.5).sum()
```

would work.